# Run a tesseract.js application for multiple pictures

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, ocr, tesseract.js

I will start a new project soon. It's about sorting pictures to it's corresponding categories.

I scanned a few thousand documents with my scanner, and I want to sort them. So the plan is to check each file for given words, and if one of the given words are in the text of the file I want to put it in the right place for it.
So my main question is, is this possible with tesseract.js and if not, are there any good options to do this? I would prefer to do that with JavaScript, and it should be a web application.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

a good plugin for you idea is [Shuffle.js](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) you will find a demo on this page.
also watch the full documentation on [View the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Vestride/Shuffle). To give you a answer: i have no idea whether that is possible with  tesseract.js